# Matching Camera view and User perspective view - Field of view

Tags: camera

I have research on internet about this issue and so far, no one comes up with the right answer. I guess this problem happens to people that use other 3D modelling programs were there is no distinction between "User perspective view" and the "Camera view".

In Blender is differentiated, but when you want to match both you are unable to find the parameter to do so. When People are asking this question they are referring about the Field of view, the angle the perspective view is applying to the image.

In the User perspective view the angle used is a more realistic one, but when you switch to Camera view, the angles look more orthogonal, (even though everything matches, Focal length 50mm, F-stop 2.8). In other 3D modelling programs, this is a parameter that is widely used: for interiors you use a range between 60-75º but in exteriors you go down to 30-45º.

I am sure there is a way to fix the field of view in Blender. Can someone direct me?

Comment: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/98596

Comment: Duarte, can you please tell me how to fix the bug? If you think is a bug, please point me to the solution. Apparently I am not the only one having this problem.

Comment: A bug means that is something embedded in the programs code, only the developers or volunteers with experience can solve that, you could report the bug using Blender > Help menu > Bug. This site is not directly related to the Blender developers